# How to use scheduleAtFixedRate for executing in each second

Tags: android

in the below code send() function is executing many times in a second,i want to execute send() once in a second,how i change the code

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        send();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            1000,
            1000);
```

send function is given below

```
void send() throws Exception, IOException
{
    s=new Socket("10.0.2.2",4200);
    r=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    while(true)
    {
        Log.e("msg","hi send\n");
        r.print("hai");
    }
}
```

Logcat output is given below

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I replaced timers with Runnables/Handlers recently, it's much easier

```
//declare at top of your activity
private Handler h = new Handler();

private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    //do stuff  

        //run again in one second
    h.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
   }
};

//trigger the runnable somewhere in your code e.g. onClickHander or onCreate etc
h.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
```

Comment: oops sorry the first line should be: private Handler h = new Handler();

Answer (score 1):

It happened for me when I used a `TaskTimer` and the phone got into sleep mode. I think it is related to `TimerTask` using `Thread.sleep()` to provide the timing. This relies on `uptimeMillis()` which according to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) -  'is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms. This is the basis for most interval timing such as `Thread.sleep(millls)`'
Solution would be either to use `AlarmManager` or `WakeLocks`.

Answer (score 0):

an easier approach would look like this:

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
     while(true) {
       send();
       try{
         Thread.sleep(1000); // pauses for 1 second
       catch(Exception e) {}
     }
  }
}.start();
```

Comment: when i use sleep,after 5 or 6 sec i got a message "application not responding"

Comment: probably due to your s and r variables being reinstantiated while previous calls to send() aren't done yet.