# timer.scheduleAtFixedRate is executed in a second not after delay time

Tags: android

i am using timer like:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CheckWifi(), 0, 50000); // 5 seconds

class Wifi extends BroadcastReceiver {

 protected class CheckWifi extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
 }
```

but `CheckWifi` class is executed in a second not after 50 second like is set in `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Why?

Is it better to use `Runnable` instead of `Timer`?

Comment: Or you replace the timer like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8027888/1315476

Comment: read the documentation, and question yourself as to the meaning of '0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CheckWifi(), 50000, 50000);
```

The second parameter specifies the delay before the first execution.
The third parameter specifies the delay between subsequent executions.