# how to use java timer ,its not work in my program

Tags: java, swing, timer, graphics2d

This method use to draw robot & i want to draw it every 1 sec draw robot one after another with a delay(not all of them at once).I used the timer but doesn't work so how to use it in my case,
robot represent rectangle and move toward the goal

```
public void paint(double[] position, double direction, int[][] pixels, double robotHalfDiagonalDistance) {
        double[] corner1, corner2, corner3, corner4;
        final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
          super.paint(g);
        corner1 = new double[2]; corner2 = new double[2];corner3 = new double[2]; corner4 = new double[2];
        corner1[0] = (position[0] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.sin(direction - pi / 4));
        corner1[1] = (position[1] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.cos(direction - pi / 4));
        corner2[0] = (position[0] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.sin(direction + pi / 4));
        corner2[1] = (position[1] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.cos(direction + pi / 4));
        corner3[0] = (position[0] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.sin(direction - pi / 4 + pi));
        corner3[1] = (position[1] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.cos(direction - pi / 4 + pi));
        corner4[0] = (position[0] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.sin(direction + pi / 4 + pi));
        corner4[1] = (position[1] + robotHalfDiagonalDistance * Math.cos(direction + pi / 4 + pi));

        int value0 = (int) corner1[0];int value1 = (int) corner1[1];
        final int[] corner1n = {value0, value1};
        int value00 = (int) corner2[0]; int value11 = (int) corner2[1];
        final int[] corner2n = {value00, value11};
        int value000 = (int) corner3[0];int value111 = (int) corner3[1];
        final int[] corner3n = {value000, value111};
        int value0000 = (int) corner4[0];int value1111 = (int) corner4[1];
        final int[] corner4n = {value0000, value1111};

        if (pixels[corner1n[0]][corner1n[1]] == 1 && pixels[corner2n[0]][corner2n[1]] == 1 && pixels[corner3n[0]][corner3n[1]] == 1
                && pixels[corner4n[0]][corner4n[1]] == 1) {

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

            Timer t = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //bottom
                    g.drawLine(corner1n[0], corner1n[1], corner2n[0], corner2n[1]);
                    //right
                    g.drawLine(corner2n[0], corner2n[1], corner3n[0], corner3n[1]);
                    //up
                    g.drawLine(corner3n[0], corner3n[1], corner4n[0], corner4n[1]);
                    ///left
                    g.drawLine(corner4n[0], corner4n[1], corner1n[0], corner1n[1]);
                    //repaint();
            }
        });
            t.start();
                       }

         else{
             System.err.println("collision ");
         }
   }
```

please help me

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394615/3992939) of how to use time for moving object and repainting.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create [a swing timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and then schedule the specified task (**drawing**) for repeated fixed-rate execution `delay`:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      // Perform a task repeatedly
  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Once the timer has been started, it waits for the initial delay before firing its first ActionEvent to registered listeners
For further reading on the subject, take a look at the link above.

Comment: Did you take a look at the given link for a full example? Maybe there is something you are doing wrong.

Comment: Here an other useful [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#Timer()).

Comment: just when use timer in main show scheduleAtFixedRate but i need to use it in method not in main

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026965/how-to-use-scheduleatfixedrate-for-executing-in-each-second) could help.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I didn't know of the existence of that, thanks.

Comment: @zoya as @AndrewThompson suggested, you can use `javax.swing.Timer`, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for more details.

Comment: @zoya I changed the answer for the swing timer use.